# Transform inside :hover could not activate

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
div img{
  position: absolute;
}
  div img:nth-child(1){
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
div img:nth-child(2){
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
img:hover{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
     <div>
           <img src="pic1.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
           <img src="pic2.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then if I hover the pictures neither of them could activate the

```
transform: scale(1);
```

But if I change the css like this:

```
div img:hover{
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Then the transform inside :hover function normally as expected. Why could this happen? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `div` before **all** css `img` style declarations.

It happens because of specificity - when you set a more specific rule, such as `div img {}`, it overrides the less specific css rule `img {}`

[About specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed
>   of different sorts of CSS selectors.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="pic1.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  <img src="pic2.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style  `div img:nth-child(1) { }` is more specific than the `img:hover{ }` style. That is why it is being overriding your style.

Either you can go with the approach you already used or you can use !important like `img:hover{ transform: scale(1) !important; }`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    div img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    div img:nth-child(1) {
      top: 50px;
      left: 80px;
      transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    
    div img:nth-child(2) {
      top: 50px;
      left: 80px;
      transform: scale(0.7);
    }
    
    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1) !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="100" height="100" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```